# Y-axis ticks not defined using Seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

We have a simple dataframe defined as;

```
df=pd.DataFrame({
'year':[2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018],
'incidents_100000':[0.8,122.03,146.28,147.56,178.71,37.73,1.04,197.23,168.87,215.71,179.28,36.69],
'City':['Baltimore','Baltimore','Baltimore','Baltimore','Baltimore','Baltimore','New Orleans','New Orleans',
       'New Orleans','New Orleans','New Orleans','New Orleans']
})
```

The goal is to get faceted bar plots for each city, Baltimore as well as New Orleans. Here is the code to obtain the `incidents_100000` corresponding to each year;

```
gnew3 = sns.catplot(x="year", y="incidents_100000", hue='City', col='City',
             data=df, saturation=.5,
             kind="bar", ci=None, height = 8, aspect=.5)
 font = {'family': 'serif',
    'weight': 'bold',
    'size': 14,
    }
plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
gnew3.fig.suptitle('Variation of Gun Incidents Per 100000 People', fontsize=18)
gnew3.set_xlabels('Year', fontsize=16)
gnew3.set_ylabels('Gun Incidents Per 100000 People', fontsize=16)
gnew3.set_xticklabels(fontdict=font)
gnew3.set_yticklabels(fontdict=font)
gnew3.set_titles(col_template='{col_name}', fontdict=font)
plt.show()
```

This code gives following plot;

[image]

As we can see we are not seeing values on y-axis ticks. But when we comment out the line `gnew3.set_yticklabels(fontdict=font)` in the code;

```
gnew3 = sns.catplot(x="year", y="incidents_100000", hue='City', col='City',
             data=df, saturation=.5,
             kind="bar", ci=None, height = 8, aspect=.5)
font = {'family': 'serif',
    'weight': 'bold',
    'size': 14,
    }
 plt.subplots_adjust(top=0.8)
 gnew3.fig.suptitle('Variation of Gun Incidents Per 100000 People', fontsize=18)
 gnew3.set_xlabels('Year', fontsize=16)
 gnew3.set_ylabels('Gun Incidents Per 100000 People', fontsize=16)
 gnew3.set_xticklabels(fontdict=font)
 #gnew3.set_yticklabels(fontdict=font)
  gnew3.set_titles(col_template='{col_name}', fontdict=font)
 plt.show()
```

This gives following plot;

[image]

Now we can see the y-axis ticks. My question is; how come when we comment the line `gnew3.set_yticklabels(fontdict=font)` we get to see the values on y-axis ticks. This seems quite contrary to me. Feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missed to set your labels while calling `set_yticklabels()`. Change this line:

```
gnew3.set_yticklabels(labels=[0, 50,100,150,200],fontdict=font)
```

**Output**

[image]